# asp repeater button text change

Tags: c#, asp.net, asprepeater

Good day, I want the text of the button inside the repeater to change dynamically based on what the sql selected values would have.

here's my code:

asp.cs

```
if (!IsPostBack) 
{
   string getEmp = "Select employeeid, photo, lastname, firstname, departmentname, designation,userType from tblEmployee e inner join tblDepartment d on d.departmentid=e.department";
   SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(getEmp,con);
   con.Open();
   SqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();
   Button btnSet = (Button)FindControl("btnSet");
   if (dr.HasRows)
   {
      if (dr.Read())
      {
         if (btnSet != null)
         {
             if (dr["userType"].ToString() == "2")
             {
                btnSet.Text = "Set as Normal User";
             }
             else
             {
                btnSet.Text = "Set as Power User";
             }
         }
      } 
   }
   Repeater1.DataSource = dr;
   Repeater1.DataBind();
   dr.Dispose();
   con.Close();
```

aspx

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
<asp:Button ID="btnSet" commandname="set" commandargument=<%# Eval  ("employeeid") %> runat="server" class="tiny success expand button"  Text="" />
```

Comment: my code doesn't seem to work. i don't know if i have the right approach on this problem. though i have tried to follow several answers found on the internet but nothing works.

Comment: dear i send you the short and working solution take a look to it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this its too much short and working

```
    <asp:Button ID="btnSet" commandname="set" commandargument=<%# Eval("employeeid") %> runat="server" class="tiny success expand button"  Text='<%# Eval("userType").ToString() == "2" ?"Set as Normal User" : "Set as Power User" %>' />
```

let me know if you need any more help

Comment: omg this actually works. Though I haven't tried other solutions that have been posted here. Thanks for the help guys. I'm gonna try and understand the answers that you gave.

Comment: ok dear just make as answer to my answer now dear and make +1

Comment: im a total noob here. first time posting a question. it says that i need atleast 15 rep to +1 =[

Comment: its ok dear i got my marks thanks dear and contact me if any help you need according to .net ans database :D

Comment: when you get 15 marks then you can +1 to some one dear

Answer (score 7):

You can subscribe to the Repeater's [ItemDatabound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event. It allows you to access the controls of the item and change them based on the values of the current item:

```
private void Repeater1_ItemDatabound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        // Retrieve button of the line
        var btn = e.Item.FindControl("btnSet") as Button;
        if (btn != null)
        {
            // Set text of button based on e.Item.DataItem;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the databind event of your repeater.

Something like:

```
 void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(Object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) 
 {
      // Execute the following logic for Items and Alternating Items.
      if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem) {

        Button btnSet = (Button)e.Item.FindControl("btnSet");
        if ( e.Item.DataItem["userType"].ToString() == "2")
        {
          btnSet.Text = "Set as Normal User";
        }
        else
        {
          btnSet.Text = "Set as Power User";
        }

      }
   }
```